# Responsive design captcha/recaptcha

Tags: ruby-on-rails, captcha, responsive-design, recaptcha, zurb-foundation

So I'm creating a rails application signup page. I've used the Zurb Foundation grid in order to create the site layout. The problem I'm having is that when the grid is resizing, the recaptcha isn't doing the same, and starts to go out of it's bounds. There doesn't seem to be a way of redesigning the layout short of editing the javascript. Does anybody know of a good responsive design solution for captcha and rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the look and feel of reCaptcha:

- https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/customization

There's no need to modify the Javascript; apply responsive CSS/HTML to work with the rest of your layout.

Comment: Sorry you missed it, though it is the first Google result for "recaptcha styling". Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

make it by css

```
@media (max-width: 444px) {

.recaptchatable #recaptcha_image {
margin: 0 auto !important;
width: 200px !important;
}
.recaptchatable .recaptcha_r1_c1, .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r3_c1, .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r3_c2, .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r7_c1, .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r8_c1, .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r3_c3, .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r2_c1, .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r4_c1, .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r4_c2, .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r4_c4, .recaptchatable .recaptcha_image_cell {

background: none !important;
}

}
```

or

```
.recaptchatable #recaptcha_image {
      width:  30em !important;
  }

  #recaptcha_image {
     display: block;
     margin: 0 auto !important;
  }

  .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r1_c1,
  .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r2_c1,
  .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r2_c2,
  .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r3_c1,
  .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r3_c2,
  .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r3_c3,
  .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r4_c1,
  .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r4_c2,
  .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r4_c4,
  .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r7_c1,
  .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r8_c1 {
      background: none !important;
  }

  .recaptcha_only_if_privacy,
  .recaptchatable td img,
  #recaptcha_reload,
  #recaptcha_switch_audio,
  #recaptcha_switch_img,
  #recaptcha_whatsthis {
      display:none;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use custom theme this will help.

```
@media (max-width: 444px) {
    .recaptchatable #recaptcha_image {
        margin: 0 !important;
        width: 200px !important;
        float:left !important;
    }
    .recaptchatable #recaptcha_image img {
        max-width:100%;
    }
    .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r1_c1, .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r3_c1, .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r3_c2, .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r7_c1, .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r8_c1, .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r3_c3, .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r2_c1, .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r4_c1, .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r4_c2, .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r4_c4, .recaptchatable .recaptcha_image_cell, .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r2_c2 {
        background: none !important;
    }
}
```